# tex4ht: How to change the order of the prev / next / up?

Tags: tex4ht

I am using tex4ht. The "arrow" that are generated are in the ordre next/prev/up. I would prefers to have them in the ordre prev / up / next, on all the pages. Is there a way to do that?
Christophe

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation:

---

```
 \Configure{crosslinks} {left-delimiter} {right-delimiter} {next} {prev} {prev-tail} {front} {tail} {up}
```

This command configures the appearance of the cross-links between hypertext pages obtained for sectioning commands.

```
 \Configure{crosslinks} 
   {}{}{$\scriptstyle\Rightarrow$} 
   {$\scriptstyle\Leftarrow$} 
   {}{}{}{$\scriptstyle\Uparrow$}
```

`\Configure{crosslinks*}{1--7 arguments}`

Links to be included and their order. Available options: next, prev, prevtail, tail, front, up. The last argument must be empty.

Default:

```
\Configure{crosslinks*}{next} 
   {prev}{prevtail} 
   {tail}{front} 
   {up}{}
```

---

So, it can be configured using the `\Configure{crosslinks*}` configuration. For example:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,2}
\Configure{crosslinks}
   {}{}{$\scriptstyle\Rightarrow$}
   {$\scriptstyle\Leftarrow$}
   {}{}{}{$\scriptstyle\Uparrow$}
\Configure{crosslinks*}{prev}{up}{next}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

A sample result:

[image]

Comment: @micha.h21 Nice answer with proper explanation....thanks to you...